# Self organized maps on mixed dataset (categoricals / numerics features )

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, self-organizing-maps, mixed-type-data

i have a dataset of mixed variables and i want to apply self organized maps on it 
how can i extend som to mixed dataset?
can i use the gower distance instead of euclidienne distance in order to calculate the distance between input and prototype vectors ?
and for the update rule i dont know to adjust it in that case ! 
is there any package or an implementation that do that in python or R.. 
please help !

Comment: i need your help please to tell me what is the changes that i should make in the basic som algorhme to make it adaptable for mixed dataset .

Comment: i think for choosing the BMU i can use the gower distance but after i dont know please help  :(

Comment: I've had similar days and used the Euclidean distance successfully.  For the categorical variables, just treat them as decimal instead of integer values.  Also, make sure that you give your categories as dummy or one-hot.  In my experience, the results are still good, but the representative weights is the nodes aren't interpretable.

Comment: i dont want to change the data i want to keep the data format for example color i want to keep it as red blue green only when we calculate the distance can i use another metric

Comment: in my projet i must keep the format of data in order not to lose information

Comment: is there a way in r to use directly data without encoding ??

Comment: While the Gower distance might be a good option, you're not going to be able to update the BMU (and other nodes) to be "closer" if you leave your categorical variables as nominal.  Continuing with your red, green, blue examples, how would you change the BMU to become "closer" to the sampled point of interest?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220773924_An_Extension_of_Self-organizing_Maps_to_Categorical_Data?fbclid=IwAR0izo375lkp5iIxnucwqgA-6Zb_rCTpXAoETlMH0ugmSWiPwfuULrl45YM

Comment: in this paper they discussed how to adjust the update rule but i didnt understand how implements in it in java :( :( :(

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220773924_An_Extension_of_Self-organizing_Maps_to_Categorical_Data?fbclid=IwAR0izo375lkp5iIxnucwqgA-6Zb_rCTpXAoETlMH0ugmSWiPwfuULrl45YM

Comment: is there a package or something that handle that i read a lot of articls and papers but i'm not able able to implement the whole algorithm please help

Comment: Interesting paper - thank you for pointing it out.   I'm not aware of an R package that implements an update rule like that described in the paper or that allows you to create your own update rule.  You could probably modify the code in either the `kohonen` or `som` package to work the way that you want.

Comment: Sorry.  I can't help you.